# How to make this lead!

Tags: sound-design, synthesizer

I long to create this synth lead sound made by Procuder "Vanic" but I don't quite get there. (First link) 
What I did so far (and turned out to be relatively similar) was creating a square wave, put unison to 2-3 and play around with detune a little and adding a little EQ and reverb. If there's a better way let me know!
But the most important aspect I can't figure out how to create is this "whiny" and even a bit "whale-ish" kind of sound (which is audible in both songs' lead melody) if you know what I mean :D 
And If you have any idea on the second-link-lead-sound feel free to tell me :D
Thank you!!

First link:

(0:56)

Second link:

(1:25)

Comment: Sounds like squarewave with some reverb. The "whiny" sound is the [portamento](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portamento). Such sounds can you create with f.e.: Sylenth1.

Comment: This is an example for this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=416hqNCrv6E

Comment: Thanks, but I already did that and still I think there's more to it..

Comment: The sound itself got a bit of "sadness" to it i think, despite the portamento

Comment: Maybe it's the key that he chose. Or the choirvoices in the background.

Comment: Even tried the same key and it's not the same.. I don't know, there must be something else, maybe a second osc..

Comment: You can try to use a second osc with a detune or an oct down. I would use square but also try other waveforms.

Comment: Without identical equipment and identical programming, it's usually impossible to get the identical sound.

Comment: It has a nice portamento slide and might even have an envelope on the pitch that quickly drops down an octave or something.

Answer (score 2):

Nice tracks! Listen closely, the "whiny" aspect may also come from a high tuned oscilator, which is of lower level, as the voice is not very bright overall. Looking at the second example mainly, try tweaking with this:

- **Osc1:** 1 Triangle Wave Osc (0 Octave) + **Osc2:** 1 Square Wave or narrow Pulse Wave (+1 Octave), mixed about 3:1 ratio respectively (mostly triangle).
- **Amp env:** A - .05sec D .8sec S 20% R .3sec (Sustain level is approximate as I was only triggering notes).
- **Amp env:** on the High Square wave, so it decays faster than the Triangle:
  D .15sec S 50% R .3sec (If you can't do this try a shallow LP Filter env.)
- Add a **(-) Pitch env** overall, leading up to the current pitch from a few semitones lower, approx .2 seconds attack.
- There may be some Unison to give depth to the high freq, but not much.
- Add quick glide/Portamento in Monophonic mode

In the first example you could try this again with less of the second Osc, and longer attack on the Pitch env.

Comment: Could try adding a few extra voices in the unison to see if it's closer too. The wideness of the sound is a combination of the unison settings and also adding a reverb with the low end rolled off.

Comment: Joel, what VST did you use for this?

Comment: I used Absynth 5. That's why it's quite specific. Not the VST though.